# how to check if an excel file is password protected using jxl

Tags: java, excel, jxl

I am trying to write and read a password protected excel file, I found that I can set and reset a password by using "com.jexcel.util.ExcelAdapter" library. 
But I could not find a method to check if file is protected.

Can any one guide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you want: [Workbook.isProtected()](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/Workbook.html#isProtected%28%29)

Comment: yeah! thanks! And how can I unprotect it for reading and editing? Should I ask user to unlock it manually? Because ExcelAdapter is just setting and restting the password and I did not find its documentation...

Comment: You should restate your question if this is what you want.